# Make Function with querySelectAll with forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, queryselectall

I want to create a javascript querySelectAll with foreach. I need to use this many times. So i want to create a function. But not working. Please help me.

```
<p id="o">one</p>
<p id="o">two</p>

<script>
function q(x,y) {
document.querySelectorAll(x).forEach(e => { e.y })
}
    
q('#o', innerHTML = 'Working');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put some code in a reusable form that you can pass around then it needs to be a **function**.

An expression is just going to be evaluated immediately.

`innerHTML = 'Working'` will assigned the string to the global variable `innerHTML` and then the pass the result (the string) to `y`.

You need it to be a function and then you need to call it.

What's more: An ID must be **unique** in a document. If you want to loop over a group of things then use a **class**.

```js
function q(x, y) {
  document.querySelectorAll(x).forEach(y)
}

q('.o', (element) => element.innerHTML = 'Working');
```

```html
<p class="o">one</p>
<p class="o">two</p>
```

Comment: is it possible to create a function that could be use q('#o', innerHTML = 'Working') ?

Comment: @MehediAlImran  — For the reasons explained in the second and third paragraphs of this answer: **no**.

Comment: (element) => element i have to write every time? can it be done by function?

Comment: That *is* doing it by function.

Comment: If i want to call element multiple time how to write it? like  element.innerHTML = 'Working');  element.innerText += 'Working'); ?